# Rxjs subscription queue

Tags: javascript, firebase, rxjs, reactive-programming

I have a firebase subscription in my angular app which fires multiple times.
How can ich achieve that the tasks are processed as a queue so that I can run each task synchronously once?

```
this.tasks.subscribe(async tasks => {
   for (const x of tasks) 
      await dolongtask(x); // has to be sync
      await removetask(x);
   });
```

The problem is that the subribe event fires when the longtask is still processing.

Comment: Make longtask return an observable that completes when the task is done and use concatMap. Be aware that this backpressure can result in a memory leak.

Comment: why do I have to return an observable from longtask?

Comment: Because concatMap expects observables. You can of course do it without observables, but then what's the point of using rxjs?

Comment: can you paste some code?

Comment: `this.tasks.pipe(concatMap(tasks => processTasks(tasks))).subscribe()`. Can't say more since you didn't say what your function does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am making a couple of assumptions from the code you gave,

- other applications add tasks to the firebase db (asynchronously), and this code is implementing the task processor.
- your firebase query returns all unprocessed tasks (in a collection) and it emits the full list every time a new task is added.
- the query will drop a task only after `removeTask()` has been run

If this is so, you need a deduping mechanism before the processor.

For the purpose of illustration, I've simulated the firebase query with a subject (renamed it to tasksQuery$) and a sequence of firebase events are simulated at the bottom of the script.
I hope it's not too confusing!

```js
console.clear()
const { mergeMap, filter } = rxjs.operators;

// Simulate tasks query  
const tasksQuery$ = new rxjs.Subject();

// Simulate dolongtask and removetask (assume both return promises that can be awaited)
const dolongtask = (task) => {
  console.log( `Processing: ${task.id}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log( `Processed: ${task.id}`);
      resolve('done')
    }, 1000);
  });
}
const removeTask = (task) => {
  console.log( `Removing: ${task.id}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log( `Removed: ${task.id}`);
      resolve('done')
    }, 200);
  });
}

// Set up queue (this block could be a class in Typescript)
let tasks = [];
const queue$ = new rxjs.Subject();
const addToQueue = (task) => {
  tasks = [...tasks, task];
  queue$.next(task);
}
const removeFromQueue = () => tasks = tasks.slice(1);
const queueContains = (task) => tasks.map(t => t.id).includes(task.id)

// Dedupe and enqueue
tasksQuery$.pipe(
  mergeMap(tasks => tasks), // flatten the incoming task array 
  filter(task => task && !queueContains(task)) // check not in queue
).subscribe(task => addToQueue(task) );

//Process the queue
queue$.subscribe(async task => {
  await dolongtask(task);
  await removeTask(task); // Assume this sends 'delete' to firebase
  removeFromQueue();
});

// Run simulation
tasksQuery$.next([{id:1},{id:2}]);
// Add after delay to show repeated items in firebase
setTimeout(() => {
  tasksQuery$.next([{id:1},{id:2},{id:3}]); 
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

IMHO, I would try and leverage the power of rxjs since we're using it here already anyway and avoid implementing a custom queuing concept as suggested by another answer (though you certainly can do that).

If we simplify the given case a bit, we just have some observable and want to perform a long-running procedure for each emission – *in sequence*. rxjs allows doing this by means of the `concatMap` operator essentially out of the box:

```
$data.pipe(concatMap(item => processItem(item))).subscribe();
```

This only assumes that `processItem` returns an observable. Since you used `await`, I assume your function(s) currently return Promises. These can be trivially converted into observables using `from`.

The only detail left to look at from the OP is that the observable actually emits an array of items and we want to perform the operation on each item of each emission. To do that, we just flatten the observable using `mergeMap`.

---

Let's put it all together. Note that if you take away preparing some stub data and logging, the actual implementation of this is only *two* lines of code (using mergeMap + concatMap).

```js
const { from, interval } = rxjs;
const { mergeMap, concatMap, take, bufferCount, tap } = rxjs.operators;

// Stub for the long-running operation
function processTask(task) {
  console.log("Processing task: ", task);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Finished task: ", task);
      resolve(task);
    }, 500 * Math.random() + 300);
  });
}

// Turn processTask into a function returning an observable
const processTask$ = item => from(processTask(item));

// Some stubbed data stream
const tasks$ = interval(250).pipe(
  take(9),
  bufferCount(3),
);

tasks$.pipe(
  tap(task => console.log("Received task: ", task)),
  // Flatten the tasks array since we want to work in sequence anyway
  mergeMap(tasks => tasks),
  // Process each task, but do so consecutively
  concatMap(task => processTask$(task)),
).subscribe(null, null, () => console.log("Done"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: I don't understand what this does beyond `tasks$.subscribe(tasks => tasks.forEach(task => processTask(task))`.

Comment: This looks like an interesting pattern if you want to add additional steps in between the `mergeMap()` and the `concatMap()`, for example `filter(task => isNewTask(task))`.

Comment: @Hiram K. Hackenbacker For starters, it answers the question, meaning it processes things sequentially. Just calling the function like you did won't guarantee that.

Comment: The only problem with the queue (effectively) internalized in the `concatMap` operator is the risk of backpressure you mention above. Perhaps it can be handled with a `map(task => delayTaskIfTooMany(task))` but I can't yet see how to add the delay into the pipeline.

Comment: BTW, I think it works without `const processTask$ = item => from(processTask(item))` since processTask returns a promise (see [Example 2](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html)).

Comment: Backpressure is a problem no matter how you do it, it's a conceptual problem. We have no information from OP how they want to deal with it, so I ignored the problem.

Comment: How can you ignore backpressure, if it is the reason to create the queue in first place?

Answer (score 0):

Leaving aside your title 'Rxjs subscription queue', you can actually fix your async/await code.

The problem is that async/await does not play nicely with for loops, see this question [Using async/await with a forEach loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

For example, you can replace the for loop as per @Bergi's answer,

### with `Promise.all()`

```js
console.clear();
const { interval } = rxjs;
const { take, bufferCount } = rxjs.operators;

function processTask(task) {
  console.log(`Processing task ${task}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(task);
    }, 500 * Math.random() + 300);
  });
}
function removeTask(task) {
  console.log(`Removing task ${task}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(task);
    }, 50);
  });
}

const tasks$ = interval(250).pipe(
  take(10),
  bufferCount(3),
);

tasks$.subscribe(async tasks => {
  await Promise.all(
    tasks.map(async task => {
      await processTask(task); // has to be sync
      await removeTask(task);
      console.log(`Finished task ${task}`);
    })
  );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

---

Better yet, you can shape the query to avoid using a for loop,

### with `mergeMap()`

```js
console.clear();
const { interval } = rxjs;
const { mergeMap, take, bufferCount } = rxjs.operators;

function processTask(task) {
  console.log(`Processing task ${task}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(task);
    }, 500 * Math.random() + 300);
  });
}
function removeTask(task) {
  console.log(`Removing task ${task}`);
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve(task);
    }, 50);
  });
}

const tasks$ = interval(250).pipe(
  take(10),
  bufferCount(3),
);

tasks$
.pipe(mergeMap(tasks => tasks))
.subscribe(
  async task => {
    await processTask(task); // has to be sync
    await removeTask(task);
    console.log(`Finished task ${task}`);
  }
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/6.3.2/rxjs.umd.js"></script>
```

Comment: `forEach`  loop doesn't play nicely with async/await, `for` - does just fine.